# Composite primary key with foreign key relationships to multiple tables. SQL Server 2008 Errors

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design

```
USE [Fk_Test2]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Owners]    Script Date: 08/20/2010 16:52:44 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Owners](
    [Owner] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Owners] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Owner] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO


/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Key]    Script Date: 08/20/2010 16:49:57 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Key](
    [owner] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [key_id] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [description] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Key] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [owner] ASC,
    [key_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Key]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Key_Owners] FOREIGN KEY([owner])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Owners] ([Owner])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Key] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Key_Owners]
GO



/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Bldg]    Script Date: 08/20/2010 16:50:29 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Bldg](
    [bldg] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [owner] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Bldg] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [bldg] ASC,
    [owner] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Bldg]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Bldg_Owners] FOREIGN KEY([owner])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Owners] ([Owner])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Bldg] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Bldg_Owners]
GO


/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[KeyToBuilding]    Script Date: 08/20/2010 17:13:52 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[KeyToBuilding](
    [owner] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [bldg] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [key_id] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_KeyToBuilding] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [owner] ASC,
    [bldg] ASC,
    [key_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[KeyToBuilding]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_KeyToBuilding_Key] FOREIGN KEY([owner], [key_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Key] ([owner], [key_id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[KeyToBuilding] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_KeyToBuilding_Key]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[KeyToBuilding]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_KeyToBuilding_Bldg] FOREIGN KEY([owner], [bldg])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Bldg] ([owner], [bldg])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[KeyToBuilding] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_KeyToBuilding_Bldg]
GO
```

Whenever I try to set this up I get an Error
"The columns in table "Key" or "Bldg" do not match an existing primary key or UNIQUE constraint.

Am I trying to implement this relationship in the wrong way? or doing something dumb?

The system is for tracking the keys (physical) people have to different buildings. That is why there is key_id and Key they aren't database keys.

Comment: It would be easier if you posted the actual DDL used to create these tables.

Comment: Consider including an Owner table with relationships to Bldg and Key

Comment: I changed out my mock up of the tables to be an actual script Also the Error I get is on the FK_KeyToBuilding_Bldg it says Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'dbo.Bldg' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_KeyToBuilding_Bldg'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the source of the syntax error;

the primary key in the Bldg table is :

```sql
    CONSTRAINT PK_Bldg PRIMARY KEY (bldg, [owner])
```

And in `KeyToBuilding` table, `FK_KeyToBuilding_Bldg` you are trying to reference `([owner], bldg)` instead of `(bldg, [owner])`

It helps if you simply clean-up the code a bit, the following executes fine:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Owners (
    [owner] varchar(10) NOT NULL

  , CONSTRAINT PK_Owners PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([owner])
) ;


CREATE TABLE dbo.[Key] (
    [owner] varchar(10) NOT NULL
  , key_id  varchar(10) NOT NULL
  , [description] varchar(10) NOT NULL

  , CONSTRAINT [PK_Key] PRIMARY KEY ([owner], key_id)
) ;

ALTER TABLE dbo.[Key] ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Key_Owners
    FOREIGN KEY([owner] REFERENCES dbo.Owners ([owner])  ;


CREATE TABLE dbo.Bldg (
    bldg    varchar(10) NOT NULL
  , [owner] varchar(10) NOT NULL

  , CONSTRAINT PK_Bldg PRIMARY KEY (bldg, [owner])
) ;

ALTER TABLE dbo.Bldg ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Bldg_Owners
    FOREIGN KEY([owner] REFERENCES dbo.Owners ([owner]);


CREATE TABLE dbo.KeyToBuilding (
    [owner] varchar(10) NOT NULL
  , bldg    varchar(10) NOT NULL
  , key_id  varchar(10) NOT NULL

    , CONSTRAINT PK_KeyToBuilding PRIMARY KEY ([owner], key_id)
);

ALTER TABLE dbo.KeyToBuilding ADD
    CONSTRAINT FK_KeyToBuilding_Key
      FOREIGN KEY([owner], key_id) REFERENCES dbo.[Key] ([owner], key_id)

  , CONSTRAINT FK_KeyToBuilding_Bldg
      FOREIGN KEY(bldg, [owner]) REFERENCES dbo.Bldg (bldg, [owner]) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create them, what method are you using to create the relationship that's giving you the error?

It could be that you're creating them backwards.

Also check if there's conflicting data in the tables.  All the rows in KeyToBuilding need to be in Bldg and Key before you can create the FK relationship.  Easiest to create the relationship when all 3 tables are empty of rows.

Comment: I'm trying to create them in the sql management console. All of the tables are empty. I click Design on KeyToBuilding and then relationships and try and set up a Foreign key with Bldg or Key as the primary table and it doesn't work.

Comment: try it the other way- click Design on Bldg or Key and set up the FK with KeyToBuilding